# Powersave governor as default Arch

Tags: arch-linux, cpu-frequency

I try to change governor from "ondemand" to "powersave" like wiki says ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling#Scaling_governors ), but everyway I want to change it, Arch always boot with "ondemand"

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
```

by the way this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cpupower.service` unit provided with Archlinux reads its settings from `/etc/default/cpupower`.

Either uncomment the `governor` setting, or add a new line so that `governor='powersave'`.

Answer (score -2):

Just add the command to /etc/rc.local, minus the 'sudo'.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Initscripts#.2Fetc.2Frc.local

Comment: initscripts are deprecated in Arch. A service file is the correct approach...